# Understanding how to use omniauth-github gem in conjunction with the Github API

Tags: ruby, api, authorization, omniauth, github-api

I've decided to use the omniauth-github gem in conjunction with the github_api gem. However, I'm not 100% sure how to use the authorization I've received back from github to use the github_api gem. I know
`Github.new basic_auth: 'user:password'` and `Github.new oauth_token 'token'` but I'm not exactly sure how to get that token as a response. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you fellow rubyists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following line of code at the beginning of your authentications/sessions/callbacks controller action:

```
render :text => "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return
```

You'll be able to inspect the contents of the hash returned by GitHub and see where the `token` is located inside the hash.

As it happens, you can get it with `token = env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token`.

You can now create a new github_api client instance with the token:

```
Github.new(oauth_token: token)
```